# How to diplay a div in Speed Mode of UC Mini Browser only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I am trying to display a div only when user is using uc mini browser in SPEED MODE (the way its done in maxfunzone.com). Below is my markup. Any help on this topic is highly appreciable.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UC Mini</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/^Mozilla\/5\.0 .+ Gecko\/$/)) {
  $(".info-box").show();
}
else {
  $(".info-box").hide();
}
});
</script>
<style>
.info-box{display: none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="info-box">
some text here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? :)

Comment: Because page deasign is breaking in uc mini speed mode. ;)

Comment: if uc mini speed doesn't break your layout, then i would have said the uc speed mode has bugs or wasn't implemented appropriately. why? it is because the speed mode has to optimize layout, cache, images , stylesheets, js files and other things that are found in your page to give user that speed mode is working. It is just a way to load things faster not in standard way but you took this idea in wrong way.

hope this helps

Comment: I know that its just a way to load things faster. But i want the user to know that switching the mode will help him/her watching the webpage without the distorted layout. That is a choice that user can make. for the same message I want to use the div. Hoping this makes sense now.

Comment: as my experience with web technology, i don't know any way out for this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html, check the following html code snippet. I think it may be helpful to you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UC Mini</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    /* webpage/global style goes here */
        h1{
            color:#008000;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <!-- Note: Style in 'noscript' tag will not reflect on out side elements when speed mode is off or javascript is turned on. 
         Switch modes in UC mini browser to check the difference.
    -->
    <style>
    /* noscript specific style goes here. */
        .info-box{font-size:12px;color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;}
        h1{
            color:#2187E7;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="info-box">Please turn on javascript or turn off speed mode to make site functional.</div>
</noscript>
<h1>HTML5 is Amazing!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```